# How to prove negations of quantifiers?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, definition, first-order-logic

It is well known that the negation of "for all x, P(x)" is "not exists an x such that not P(x)".

Same on the other side, the negation of "there exists an x such that P(x)" is "not for all / any x, not P(x)".

Is there proof of these concepts or are they taken as given axioms or self-evident concepts?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I think he was trying to say that $\neg\exists xP(x)$ is the same as $\forall x(\neg P(x))$ and vice versa

Comment: Sorry I meant equivalences yes, like if all the people in the room are sleeping then there does not exist a person in the room who is awake. If there exists a blue marble in the box then it's not true that all the marbles are e.g. red (not blue).

Comment: If you want a rigorous proof, first you'd probably need a rigorous _definition_ to work with.

Comment: Intuitively, $\exists x,P(x)$ is $$P(x_0)\lor P(x_1)\lor P(x_2)\lor\dotsb$$ and $\forall x,P(x)$ is $$P(x_0)\land P(x_1)\land P(x_2)\land\dotsb$$, so that $\lnot\exists\equiv\forall\lnot$ is kind of like an infinite version of De Morgan's law. (Remember that De Morgan says that $$\lnot(P(x_0)\lor P(x_1)\lor\dotsb\lor P(x_n))$$ is the same as $$\lnot P(x_0)\land\lnot P(x_1)\land\dotsb\land\lnot P(x_n)$$.)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that those concepts are taken as "axioms". Those are fundamentals of logic and its existence.

If not all people wear blue shirts, then there must be people who don't wear blue shirts.

If there are no people who ride dinosaurs, then that means that *everyone doesn't* ride a dinosaur.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck don't confuse the *logical connectives* **and** and **or** for *quantifiers* **for all** and **exists**. They are not the same

Comment: While it is true that you can think of these quantifier laws as generalizations of De Morgan's laws, they are *very* much more general. For instance, the statement "$P_1$ AND $P_2$" is equivalent to the statement $\forall i \in \{1,2\}, P_i$. Their negations are equivalent too: the negation of the first is "(NOT $P_1$) OR (NOT $P_2$)" and the negation of the second is $\exists i \in \{1,2\}$, NOT $P_i$". Similarly, for any $k$ you can show that an AND of $n$ statements is the same as a $\forall$ over a set of size $n$ (and similar for OR and $\exists$).

Comment: But quantifying over infinite sets is very much beyond what you can handle with De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 0):

Quantificational logic has a clear formal semantics defined for these two logical operators: it basically provides a formal way of defining what the statements mean.

First: an interpretation $I$ for a logic sentence $\varphi$ is defined as a set of objects (called its domain $D$), together with mappings from all constant symbols, function symbols, and predicate symbols to these objects, functions defined over these objects, and sets of tuples of these objects, respectively.

Second: using an interpretation $I$, we can then define what it takes for some sentence $\varphi$ to be true according to some interpretation $I$. We will write this as $I \vDash \varphi$.  This definition will be spelled out for all logical symbols, including the quantifiers.

In particular, the formal semantics for quantifiers is defined as:

$$I \vDash \forall x \ \varphi(x) \text{  iff for all objects } d \in D: I[d/c] \vDash \varphi(c)$$

$$I \vDash \exists x \ \varphi(x) \text{ iff for some object }d \in D: I[d/c] \vDash \varphi(c)$$

where $I[d/c] $ is the interpretation that extends interpretation $I$ by interpreting a new constant symbol $c$ ('new' as in: one that does not already occur in $\varphi(x)$) as object $d$

Third: The logical equivalence of two sentences $\varphi$ and $\psi$ is now defined as:

$$\varphi \Leftrightarrow \psi$$

$$ \text{ iff }$$

$$\text{For any interpretation } I: I \vDash \varphi \text{ iff } I \vDash \psi $$

Using these definitions, we can now prove an equivalence like  $\neg \forall x \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x \ \neg \varphi(x)$:

For any interpretation $I$ with domain $D$:

$$I \vDash \neg \forall x \ \varphi(x)$$

$$\text{iff (by semantics of }\neg )$$

$$\text{not }I \vDash \forall x \ \varphi(x)$$

$$\text{iff (by semantics of }\forall$$

$$\text{not for all objects }d \in D: I[d/c] \vDash \varphi(c)$$

$$\text{iff (by pure logic)}$$

$$\text{for some object }d \in D: \text{ not }I[d/c] \vDash \varphi(c)$$

$$\text{iff (by semantics of }\neg)$$

$$\text{for some object } d \in D: I[d/c] \vDash \neg \varphi(c)$$

$$\text{iff (by semantics of }\exists)$$

$$I \vDash \exists x \ \neg \varphi(x)$$

So, since we have now shown that for any interpretation $I$:

$$I \vDash \neg \forall x \ \varphi(x) \text{ iff } I \vDash \exists x \ \neg \varphi(x)$$

we have that

$$\neg \forall x \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x \ \neg \varphi(x)$$

I'll leave the proof that:

$$\neg \exists x \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \ \neg \varphi(x)$$

to you as an exercise